# Routing through 'a' tag in MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am facing a redirect problem in my MVC application with 'a' tag. This is the code that i am using in my page

```
<li><a href="/infra/#tabs-0" class="cbp-tm-icon-1 menu-anchor-Style">Library</a></li>
<li><a href="/infra/#tabs-1" class="cbp-tm-icon-2 menu-anchor-Style">Computer Lab</a></li>
<li><a href="/infra/#tabs-2" class="cbp-tm-icon-3 menu-anchor-Style">Language Lab</a></li>
<li><a href="/infra/#tabs-3" class="cbp-tm-icon-4 menu-anchor-Style">Science Lab</a></li>
<li><a href="/infra/#tabs-4" class="cbp-tm-icon-5 menu-anchor-Style ">Sports, Social & Cultural</a></li>
```

Here '/infra' is my Custom route and 'tabs-0,tab-1,...' all used to make some UI changes in the same page. Here my problem is for the first time when i am selecting an item like 'Computer Lab' then it will redirect to the same page, if i am selecting another menu item from the same page itself, then it will not redirect. still in the same page but i can see the change URL but cannot redirect

Comment: don't use `#` tag, It has special meaning. It is [Fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Comment: So do you want to redirect or or not? You say `tabs-0` is used for UI changes while complaining that it's not doing a redirect.

Comment: Stijn : I Actually want to redirect to custom 'infra' route.. #tabs-0 is used to scroll specific position in my your page

Answer (score 0):

It's browser behaviar. If you have `#` sign in url and url is current page then it won't redirect. If you want to call controller then remove `#` sign.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you need to use the href link in the following manner.

```
href=<%:Url.Action("infra","tabs-0") %>
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

The "#" character is a special character to redirect to an anchor in your page. Don't use it in your case because you want to redirect to another page, not to scroll to a specific position in your page.

In your case the URL with the hashtag was correct because that was processed client-side by the browser.

Comment: Sorry : I Actually want to redirect to custom 'infra' route.. and also #tabs-0 is used to scroll specific position in my your page

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
> <li id="liTask" style="display: block;"><a href="" id="TaskUrl" ></a></li>
>
>  $('#TaskUrl').attr('href', '/infra/tabs-0');
> ```